# Customize webform-fields error messages

Tags: 7, webforms

I'm using [Webforms](https://drupal.org/project/webform) module and, in particular, a Date field. Using built-in validation and intentionally triggering the validation error, the message looks like follows:

```
The entered date must be 04/04/1914 or later.
```

Have no error here. **What I need** is to customize that error message (I need to show (1) a different message, and (2) in a different language).

**Question**: How can I alter the webform to override the message with my custom one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go ahead and download this https://drupal.org/node/1209450 module in zip. there are two zips you can download any one. here is the code can you use now

```
function modulename_message_alter(&$message) {

    if(isset($message->messages['error'])){
       foreach($message->messages['error'] as &$val) {
        if(preg_match('@The entered date must be \w+/\w+/\w+ or \w+.@',$val)){
            $val='This is not correct date';
        }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not working: my hook (ensured replacing modulename with my actual module name) is never invoked.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli did u clear cache?

Comment: yes, the first think I thought about, was in the treacherous cache.

Comment: ok, dpm($message) and see do you get some thing?

Comment: I made it work. Don't know what happened ... just reinstalled/reactivated the module.

Comment: @FelixEve I'm glad you liked it.